# What's the cheapest transport to get from Ataturk International aiport to the Taksim Square area of Istanbul?

Tags: budget, public-transport, airport-transfer, istanbul, isl

I'm flying to Istanbul tomorrow afternoon and would like to know the cheapest way to get from the airport (Ataturk) to the Taksim Square area. I'm sure there are many options and some will be easier or more comfortable but I am on a shoestring budget and sometimes like to do things the hard way as the less wealthy locals might have to.

Comment: Tomorrow afternoon? A short answer: A single public transport token (1.75 TL) will at least take you to Askaray on the metro (I don't think you can change lines on one token). And then the walk isn't that bad. Bit of hill on the other side of the estuary wont that much fun if you've got a load of luggage (should only hit 25C tomorrow).

Comment: I think I have one of those tokens from my last trip!

Comment: transport tokens are now 2 TL (December 2011)

Comment: Istanbul transport token prices have risen yet again to 3 TL!

Comment: 4 TL (July 2014)

Comment: if the timing is right, it's possible you could go for free as part of the stopover tour offered by Turkish Airlines - http://www.istanbulinhours.com/faq

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Municpal bus 96T](http://www.iett.gov.tr/saat/orer.php?hid=Saatler&hatcode=96T&a=q) is probably the cheapest, at 3.00 lira (~$2 USD), but it takes very long (~1.5h at times) and is often packed. Havas bus is faster and costs 10 lira (~$6.50 USD).

If you plan to use public transport a lot, buy the Akbil pass (saves a bit of money and you don't need to dig for coins all the time).

The trip is also possible via metro, but involves changing over twice (Zeytinburnu to tram and a short walk at [Karakoy to Tunel](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=istanbul&hl=en&ll=41.022622,28.974799&spn=0.002831,0.001794&sll=13.764842,100.538473&sspn=0.029157,0.014355&z=19)). This takes 3 tokens (jetons), and costs 3 x 3 = 9 lira (~5 USD), in 2012.

([details](http://www.turkeytravelplanner.com/go/Istanbul/Transport/airport_trans.html))

Comment: How long roughly do you think the Havas bus and metro are? Is Tom Hawtin's comment about needing multiple tokens on the metro due to chaning accurate? And to clarify, are you saying the metro would not be much more expensive than the municipal bus or than the Havas bus?

Comment: Not sure about Havas  bus (never took it), but the metro/tram is about 40-60 min depending on connection waits. You'd need 3 tokens, but they're cheaper (~2 lira, I think). If you have heavy luggage, metro is not so great, due to changes).

Comment: As it turned out I had one jeton from last year and not enough lira for the Havaş bus. The jetons now cost 1.75 lira and I had just enough lira to buy the two more I needed. Changing at Zytinburnu was no problem but as for Funicular I did not see it and still cannot find it on the metro map now that I'm here. On the map on the metro it looked like I needed to change at Kabataş but when I got off there I could not find another joining metro line and ended up walking )-:

Comment: @hippietrail -- thanks for the update. I linked a map to help people find the Funicular in the future (station name is Karakoy).

Comment: Thanks dbkk. So the funicular is a different thing but accepts the same jetons? (I know what a funicular is, but not whether it's considered part of the metro system in Istanbul)

Comment: transport tokens are now 2 TL (December 2011)

Comment: The funicular is at Kabataş not Karaköy.

Comment: @SigueSigueBen there are funiculars at both Kabataş and Karaköy.

Comment: @dbkk Yes, but only the one at Kabataş is called a funicular (it is _the_ funicular in Turkish). The one at Karaköy is called _Tünel_.

Comment: For reference, a taxi to the airport costs between 40 and 50TL (may 2012).

Comment: Transport tokens rose in price again some time prior to September 2012 to 3 TL!

Comment: 4 TL (July 2014)

Answer (score 9):

There are three public transport options if you are trying to minimise costs.

1. Take the direct bus between Atatürk airport and Taksim square. This bus is a double fare bus and can be slow. In the early hours of the morning, it can be very fast, however. I travelled from Taksim to the airport in about 20 minutes on this bus once.
2. Take the metro to Aksaray and transfer to a bus going to Taksim. This will cost you the same as the direct bus but can be faster as the metro skips much of the traffic. The walk between the metro stop and the bus stop is less than 5 minutes and involves an underpass and then an overpass (which crosses over the tramline). The bus stop is called Yusufpaşa and there are several passing buses which travel to Taksim, passing under the aqueduct and then crossing the Golden Horn via Atatürk bridge.
3. Take the metro to Aksaray and then walk to Taksim square. The walk would take 45 minutes to an hour and there is a hill involved after you cross the bridge. This would be the cheapest since you'd only be paying a single fare.

The tram line between Zeytinburnu and Kabataş is the worst option, especially if you change lines at Zeytinburnu. It travels very slowly (especially between Zeytinburnu and Aksaray) and it does not travel to Taksim, so you will have to walk uphill or pay for a third fare. The best bet with the tram is to change lines at Aksaray, but this involves the same 5 minute walk as going to the bus stop

If you do take the tram, you can get off at the last stop (Kabataş) and, as mentioned, take the funicular up to Taksim at the north end of İstiklâl street. You can also get off the tram earlier at Karaköy, where there is the two-stop Tünel (Istanbul's 100-year-old metro line) that takes you to the south end of İstiklâl, from where it is a pleasant 20-minute walk to Taksim square. Walking from Karaköy up to İstiklâl is also possible and the road goes right past the Galata Tower.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Istanbulkart (Istanbul's Oyster Card) you can make it to Taksim with 4.75 TL.

1. Atatürk - Zeytinburnu (M1A): 2.15 TL
2. Zeytinburnu - Kabatas (T1): 1.45 TL
3. Kabatas - Taksim (F1): 1.15 TL

Buying 3 Jetons would make 12 TL instead. Using the Istanbulkart is only useful if you use public transportation more than that one time since it costs 6 TL to get the card in the first place.

---

Source:

http://www.iett.gov.tr/en/main/pages/public-transport-fare-schedule/317

http://www.istanbul-ulasim.com.tr/media/24900/ag_2200px_1546px-01.jpg